# How can I add an Object created in class PostingPage to a list of Objects in class HomePage

Tags: java, android-studio, class

I have a class named ImageItem where you can create a product with different attributes.
I also have the PostingPage where you enter the attributes needed to create an ImageItem, and a HomePage where you display ImageItems created in PostingPage. The HomePage contains a List of ImageItem to store products posted.

this is the constructor of ImageItem:

```
public ImageItem(int imageResource,Bitmap bitmap,String description,float price,Categories category) {
    mImageResource = imageResource;
    mDescription = description;
    mPrice=price;
    mCategory=category;
    mBitmap=bitmap;
    id++;
    mId=id;
}
```

this is where you post your product in PostingPage:

```
            Intent intent=new Intent(PostingPage.this,HomePage.class);
            ImageItem newItem=new ImageItem(imgView.getId(),imgView.getDrawingCache(),descriptionText.getText().toString(),Float.parseFloat(priceText.getText().toString()),catName);
            HomePage homePage=new HomePage();
            homePage.AddObject(newItem.getImageResource(),newItem.GetImage(),newItem.getDescription(),newItem.getPrice(),newItem.GetCategory());
            startActivity(intent);
```

and this is the HomePage:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_page);

    InitializeObjects();

    DisplayItems(R.id.trending_list,CreateTrendingList());
    DisplayItems(R.id.MOWYL_list,CreateTrendingList());

    InitializeButton();
}


void InitializeObjects(){
    objects=new HashMap<>();
    List<ImageItem> carsList=new ArrayList<>();
    
    List<ImageItem> videoGamesList=new ArrayList<>();

    objects.put(Categories.Cars,carsList);
    objects.put(Categories.VideoGames,videoGamesList);
}

public void AddObject(int imageResource, Bitmap bitmap, String description, float price, Categories category){
    ImageItem newItem=new ImageItem(imageResource,bitmap,description,price,category);
    objects.get(category).add(newItem);
    CreateTrendingList();
}
```